# Are there any strategies (or libraries) for performant varints and varlongs in Java?

Tags: java

Currently, I am serializing some long data using `DataOutput.writeLong(long)`. The issue with this is obvious: there are many many cases where the longs will be quite small. I was wondering what the most performant varint implementation is? I've seen the strategy from protocol buffers, and testing on Random long data (which probably isn't the right distribution to test against), I'm seeing a pretty big performance drop (about 3-4x slower). Is this to be expected? Are there any good strategies for serializing longs as quickly as possible while still saving space?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

How about using the standard `DataOutput` format for serializing and using a generic compression algorithm such as `GZIPOutputStream` for compression?

Answer (score 0):

The protocol buffer encoding is actually pretty good but isn't helpful with random longs - it is mostly useful if your longs are probably going to be small positive or negative numbers (let's say in the +/- 1000 range 95% of the time).

Numbers in this range will typically get encoded in 1, 2 or 3 bytes compared with 8 for a normal long. Try it with this sort of input on a large set of longs, you can often often get 50-70% space savings.

Of course calculating this encoding has some performance overhead, but if you are using this for serialisation then CPU time will not be your bottleneck anyway - so you can effectively ignore the encoding cost.